# Program to iterate through lists within a list

Tags: r

I have a list containing a number of lists containing character vectors. The lists are always arranged so that the first list contains a vector with a single element, the second list contains a vector with two elements and the third contains one or more vectors containing three elements.

```
fruits <- list(
  list(c("orange")),
  list(c("pear", "orange")),
  list(c("orange", "pear", "grape"),
       c("orange", "lemon", "pear"))
)
```

I need to iterate through the lists in order to remove the elements from the vector in the previous list. i.e. I would first find the value from the vector in the first list ('orange') and remove it from the vector in the second list, then take the values from the second list ("pear", "orange") and remove them from both vectors in the third list, so I ended up with:

```
new_fruits <- list(
  list(c("orange")),
  list(c("pear")),
  list(c("grape"),
       c("lemon"))
)
```

I should add that I have had a go at doing this, but I'm finding the lists within lists make it quite complicated and my solution is long and not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
new_fruits <- s <- c()
for (k in seq_along(fruits)) {
  new_fruits[[k]] <- lapply(fruits[[k]],function(x) x[!x%in%s])
  s <- union(s,unlist(fruits[[k]]))
}
```

which gives

```
> new_fruits
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "orange"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "pear"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "grape"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "lemon"
```

Comment: This is great and also works for the few cases I have where the first list is missing. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea where we unlist, convert to strings and resplit to differentiate between different vectors of same element. We then unlist one more time and get the unique values, i.e.

```
as.list(unique(unlist(strsplit(unlist(lapply(fruits, function(i) sapply(i, toString))), ', '))))

#[[1]]
#[1] "orange"

#[[2]]
#[1] "pear"

#[[3]]
#[1] "grape"

#[[4]]
#[1] "lemon"
```

Comment: Thanks. Will take me a while to figure out what is going on here!

Comment: The explanation should give you a start. The take it apart and run it piece by piece (from inside out ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

Another two compact options:

```r
> mapply(fruits,append(list(list("")),fruits[-length(fruits)], after = length(fruits)), FUN = function(x,y) sapply(x,function(item)list(setdiff(item,y[[1]]))))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "orange"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "pear"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "grape"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "lemon"
```

or also

```r
> append(fruits[[1]],mapply(fruits[-1],fruits[-length(fruits)], FUN = function(x,y) sapply(x,function(item)list(setdiff(item,y[[1]])))), after = length(fruits))
[[1]]
[1] "orange"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "pear"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "grape"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "lemon"
```